# Push Notification issue in iPhone 5,5s

Tags: swift2

After published to AppStore in Swift 2.0, in iPhone 5,5s app freezes when starts. Push Notification has been integrated into the app. Please tell me how to debug the app as no crash report is coming to app. Also guide how to get/find the issue behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the allocations profile from your instruments to know what all is getting allocated. It may be a case of sigkill where the os watchdog might be killing your app. Try printing logs after each method call to know which method is actually blocking.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply...  Pls tell me when I am using  " if application.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications() " then I got notifications for IOS8 but if I don't use I don't receive notifications for IOS8 but I do get it for IOS9. The code snippet I am using for IOS8 is same as IOS9 except the application.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications() check.